# How to remove spaces from nested JSON nodes in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert JSON documents into Parquet, from a source I cannot control.  The schema is self-describing and evolving.

Spaces need to be removed from field names in nested nodes to convert/write from spark dataframe to Parquet.

**How can Spark (on python) remove spaces from field names in a nested schema?**

Following seems to work on a flat schema, but does not seem to work for a nested tree.

```
exprs = [col(column).alias(column.replace(' ', '_')) for column in jsonDF.columns]
newDF = jsonDF.select(*exprs)
newDF.write \
.format("parquet") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save("/path/to/parquet_test1")
```

Here is a representative made up schema.  Note the spaces in field names at different depths of the node tree.

```
root
|-- Browser Info: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- Operating System: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Android: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- BlackBerryOS: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- ChromeOS: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Linux: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Mac OS X: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Windows: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- iOS: double (nullable = true)
|    |-- Browser Types: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Chrome: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Firefox: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- IE 10: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- IE 8: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- IE 9: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Opera: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Safari 5: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Safari 6: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Safari 7: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can provide the code in Scala I hope that helps.
This is a bit dirty way to do implement what you are asking, but would do the trick.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


  val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json("path")
  val oldSchema = jsonDF.columns.toIterator
  val newSchema = oldSchema.map(x => x.replaceAll(" ", "")).toIterator

  val schema = new ListBuffer[String]()

  while (oldSchema.hasNext) {
    val oldSchemValue = oldSchema.next()
    val newSchemaValue = newSchema.next()

    schema += s"${oldSchemValue} as ${newSchemaValue}"
  }

  val newJsonDF = jsonDF.selectExpr(schema.toList.head, schema.toList.tail: _*)
```